# Azure static website use my own ssl certificate?

Tags: azure, azure-static-website-hosting

I have my own certificate that I want to use with azure static website(not web app, we use the one based on blob storage), but looks uploading my own certificate is not supported,  is there any workaround or solution for this ?
Note : the static website is private with privatelink and the dns name is private (only used in internal network with our own dns server on premise)

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Static web app **We cannot bind our own certificates** like as in Basic App Service. It provides it's own free certificate.

But we have a workaround here, through which You can bring your own certificate (I haven't tested it yet):-

1. First you need to set up Azure Front Door: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/front-door-manual
2. Then you need to configure SSL with your own certificate

Hope this helps!